# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop overheating

Tags: 12.04, overheating

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on a HP Pavillion g6 laptop with quad core i5 processors, 4GB RAM, a hybrid graphics of Intel and Radeon 6400M.

The laptop is generating too much of heat, what should I be doing?

This is a completely fresh installation, and I did not install any other driver in the system yet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Catalyst Driver using instructions from the following link

   http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide
2. If the problem still persists, install TLP

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
   sudo tlp start
   ```